# can we configure the broker to create the auto generated multicast queue name with the address name

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-artemis

I ham running an Artemis broker 2.18 with on all addresses (match="#")

```
<auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
<auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
```

When I start to consume from a non-existing multicast queue using Camel JMS component

```
from("jms:topic:my_topic")
```

The generated queue name under the my_topic address is cryptic: 5ae02282-6685-4558-bde4-6bf3dd61c146

[image: Artemis console]

I know that I can use FQDN name to properly create it:

```
from("activemq:topic:my_topic::my_topic")
```

but this requires changing the client configuration.

Is there a way to configure the broker to use the address name as the default queue name?
In this case that the queue name would be 'my_topic'

Comment: The multicast routing is supposed to be used to implement a publisher/subscribers model with a queue for each subscriber. Why do you need to configure a queue name?

Comment: I need a queue name because I am bridging an ActiveMQ network of brokers with an Artemis one. I am consuming topics from ActiveMQ if there is a consumer for it on Artemis. I am using that name  to subscribe on ActiveMQ. But if the name is a hash then it does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the address name of the Artemis multicast queue as the topic name on ActiveMQ.
I query the address name of the multicast queue using jolokia's addressInfo operation